# PHP7.3でメールから件名や本文を取り出したい

Tags: php

お世話になります。
PHPでメールから件名や本文を取得したいと考えています。
[php-mime-mail-parser](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser)というライブラリが使いやすそうで利用を検討していました。
しかし、このライブラリを利用するには「mailparse」という拡張機能を導入する必要があるようで、レンタルサーバーなど、ルート権限がなく、拡張機能を導入できない環境では動かないことが判明しました。
また、検索してみると、PEARを利用する記事がよくヒットしましたが、PEARは現在あまりメンテナンスされていないようで、今後のPHPのバージョンアップ等で動かなくなる可能性があり、心配しています。
何か他におすすめのライブラリ等があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。
環境は、PHP7.3、サーバーはApacheのレンタルサーバーを想定しています。
また、解析するメールはPHPへパイプされたメールを利用したいと考えています。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 前提/想定している環境やソフトウェア版数等の詳細情報が無いと答えが出にくいのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問文を編集しておきました。また、タイトルもPHPのバージョンがわかるよう、変更しました。

Comment: 自分だけでやりますという記事がこちら。[【PHP】メールの生データを力業で成型してみた【MIMEヘッダ編】](https://qiita.com/next1ka2u/items/11dece9fc7add4ecb424) 条件は合わなそうですが冒頭にライブラリがいくつか挙げられています。他にも当人による自分でやる関連の記事があるのでたどってみては？

Comment: 候補に挙げたライブラリの様にメールファイルを直接参照する方法の他にも、POP3やIMAP経由でメールサーバから受信する方法もあるので、それらも踏まえて質問内容を絞り込むと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。独力でなんとかするのは、かなり難しそうですね。とりあえず、メールの取得方法を記載しておきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php-imapでもメールの受信が簡単にできます。試してみて。

Answer (score 0):

お世話になります。
結局mailparseがなんとかユーザー環境にインストールできたので、[php-mime-mail-parser](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser)を利用することにしました。
参考までにコンパイルのためのソースを貼り付けておきます。

```
mkdir ~/.local/src && cd $_
git clone https://github.com/php/pecl-mail-mailparse.git
cd pecl-mail-mailparse
phpize
./configure
sed -i 's/^\(#error .* the mbstring extension!\)/\/\/\1/' mailparse.c
make
mkdir ~/.local/php/ext
cp modules/mailparse.so ~/.local/php/ext/
```

あとは、レンタルサーバー等のphp.ini設定で

```
extension=/home/xxxxx/.local/php/ext/mailparse.so
```

を追加することで、ｍmailparseを利用できるようになると思います。